# How to calculate Total Working hours, first in and last out of Night Shift Employee in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

If Employee in Night shift like 5:30 Pm to next day Morning 2:30 am. So  I could not able to calculate..

Shift Table

```
 UserID     ShiftName    Start   End     
 2267     Night Shift-1  17:30  02:30
```

Employee LogInTable

```
  UserId    LogDate                   Details    
  2267  2016-01-04 20:52:08.000      in         
  2267  2016-01-04 22:09:22.000      Out
  2267  2016-01-04 23:00:07.000      in
  2267  2016-01-05 00:35:46.000      Out
  2267  2016-01-05 01:02:31.000      in
  2267  2016-01-05 03:57:16.000      Out
  2267  2016-01-05 18:43:50.000      in
  2267  2016-01-05 19:05:04.000      Out
  2267  2016-01-05 19:10:20.000      in
  2267  2016-01-05 22:26:00.000      Out
  2267  2016-01-05 23:27:24.000      in
  2267  2016-01-06 03:45:16.000      Out
```

Using this Query

```
  select UserId=t.UserId,LogDate, [LogIn] = Min(t.LogDate),LogOut = Max(t.LogDate), t.LogDate FROM (SELECT *, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, C1 ORDER BY LogDate)FROM  LoginTable ) t  group by t.User,t.LogDate
```

I Got Result Like :

```
 UserID     LogIn                  LogOut                         LogDate
 2267   2016-01-04 20:52:08.000  2016-01-04 22:09:22.000   2016-01-04 00:00:00.000
 2267   2016-01-04 23:00:07.000  2016-01-04 23:00:07.000   2016-01-04 00:00:00.000
 2267   2016-01-05 00:35:46.000  2016-01-05 00:35:46.000   2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
 2267   2016-01-05 01:02:31.000  2016-01-05 03:57:16.000   2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
 2267   2016-01-05 18:43:50.000  2016-01-05 19:05:04.000   2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
 2267   2016-01-05 19:10:20.000  2016-01-05 22:26:00.000   2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
 2267   2016-01-05 23:27:24.000  2016-01-05 23:27:24.000   2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
 2267   2016-01-06 03:45:16.000  2016-01-06 03:45:16.000   2016-01-06 00:00:00.000
```

If i use this query just add 1 day in Logout for Night Shift then i can get Next day Login Information

```
 select UserId,[date], min(convert(char(5), [Login], 108))as FirstIN,min(convert(char(5),DATEADD(day,1, LogOut),108))  as LastOUT   from  
 LoginTable  group by UserId,[date]
```

I tried Min,Max,DateAdd,DateDiff, But I got only  wrong Output:

```
  EmpId     date           FirstIN  LastOUT
  2267    2016-01-04        20:52   22:09
  2267    2016-01-05        00:35   00:35
```

But I want Output :

```
  EmpId     date           FirstIN  LastOUT
  2267    2016-01-04        20:52   03:57
  2267    2016-01-05        18:43   03:45
```

Could Any one Help for this?????

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Too many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...)

Comment: Provide whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: @Ambrish I did not try because confused to write the query

Comment: I tried select UserId,min(convert(char(5), LogDate, 108))as time, Convert(varchar,LogDate,106) as Datess   from DeviceLogs_1_2016 where C1='in' and  UserId=2272
 group by UserId,Convert(varchar,LogDate,106)

Comment: Hi @Jarlh and Ambrish Please help for this edited post.

Comment: Are you aware that your logouts are before your logins?

Comment: @Ambrish,@Jarlh,@Carra  I almost finished my project. I am very poor in sql. So kindly help to this... Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you shift the LogIn date by the number of second between midnight (0=00:00) and the start of the shift, it gets the date of the shift and it can be used in a GROUP BY.

Query:

```
WITH s AS (
SELECT s.UserID, e.LogIn, e.LogOut
    , [DATE] = CAST(DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, s.[Start], 0), e.LogIn) as date)
FROM @Shifts s
INNER JOIN @Employees e ON s.UserID = e.UserID) SELECT s.UserID, [DATE], FirstIN = CAST(MIN(LogIn) as time), LastOut = CAST(MAX(LogOut) as time)FROM s GROUP BY s.UserID, [DATE];
```